# cannot find symbol in my java wordcount program

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;
class WordCount{
static String word;
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int count=0;
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the sentence");
    word=in.nextLine();
    for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++){   
        if(i!=word.length())
        if(word.charAt(i)==' ' || word.charAt(i)!='.' && isNotSpace(word,i))
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The number of words in the sentence are : " +count);
}
static boolean isNotSpace(String word,int i)
{
    if(word.charAt[i+1]!=' ')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
}
```

Here I declared a static variable called word and called the "isNotSpace" method by passing the word variable from the main method. But I get an error in the "isNotSpace" method:

```
WordCount.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
        if(word.charAt[i+1]!=' ')
               ^
  symbol:   variable charAt
  location: variable word of type String
1 error
```

Comment: The `if(i!=word.length())` test is useless as the loop stops before.

Comment: A big TYPO - you wrote `word.charAt(i)` couple of lines above `word.charAt[i+1]` and still cannot figure out the problem, Put some effort that will help you only

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Comment: Read the String javadoc entry.  Focus on the "split()" method.

Answer (score 6):

You've just got a typo by the looks of it. You want:

```
word.charAt(i+1) // parentheses, not brackets.
```

You may also find your code a lot easier to read and deal with if you put some spaces around your operators. I find that makes it much easier to notice small mistakes like this one. e.g.

```
if (word.charAt(i + 1) != ' ')
```